# How to implement Liquibase changelogs when project is using Tomcat JNDI datasource lookup

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, liquibase

I am working on a project currently using JNDI to look up datasources, the file is called `jdbc_customer.properties` and it is located in the Tomcat lib folder. In my java code, it is set up to grab the `jdbc_customer.properties` file in my `PersistenceManager.java` class.

Currently my project is running on 3 different databases, DB2, Oracle, and MS SQL, it becomes hard to maintain all three updates for different databases, so I am trying to use liquibase to maintain database versioning.

Here is part of the `PersistenceManager.java` code that is handling database selection:

```
private EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory(){
    Properties jdbc_cust = new Properties();
    InputStream stream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("jdbc_customer.properties");
    String vendor = jdbc_cust.getProperty("OPT.dbvendor");
    if ("oracle".equals(vendor)) {
            dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect";
            } else if ("db2".equals(vendor)) {
                dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect";
            } else if ("mssql".equals(vendor)) {
                dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect";
            }
```

What I am trying to do right now,is to figure out a way to run Liquibase changelog on deployment based on the correct version of databases. I have already created 3 different versions of changelogs, how do I properly implement it into my project?

Answer (score 0):

Changesets and other tags in the Liquibase changelog can be marked with a dbms attribute to specify what database engines they should apply to. Liquibase figures out the dbms it is working with at runtime and does filtering of the changelog so that only applicable changes are considered.

This [page](http://www.liquibase.org/databases.html) lists the currently available dbms types along with their 'short name':
Here is an example showing how you could use the modifySql tag to generate some platform specific SQL:

```
<changeSet id="1" author="nvoxland">
    <createTable tableName="person">
        <column name="id" type="bigint"/>
        <column name="firstname" type="varchar(255)"/>
        <column name="lastname" type="varchar(255)"/>
    </createTable>
    <modifySql>
         <replace replace="bigint" with="long"/>
    </modifySql>
    <modifySql dbms="mysql">
         <append value=" engine innodb"/>
    </modifySql>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: I was actually looking for some Java implementation suggestion because all the changelogs are created, I also made changes to them, modify or create new changelogs are not really what I am trying to do as of now.

Comment: If you want to do this in Java, I would suggest looking at the Liquibase source code itself.